# Get ids of problematic objects when calling is_valid(raise_exception=True)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have code that looks something like this:

```
serializer = CreateSerializer(data=data)
try:
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
except ValidationError as e:
    print e
serializer.save()
```

When an exception occurs, it looks like `{'detail': {'topic': [u"Invalid pk '3' - object does not exist."]}}`

My goal is to save an instance with many-to-many relations. Currently the instance doesn't get saved if one of the linked rows is missing due to the exception getting thrown. What I'd like to do is to retry saving the instance without the problematic relations, meaning that I'd like to remove the missing object id from `data` and retrying. Is there any clean way to do this without having to resort to something like parsing the error message?

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to customize field validators so they return additional machine-readable information.